# Search exact match word in MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have one page with listing of all data in tabular format. now i want to implement search functionality in it.but here i want to search exact match word not like that word.

MySQL Querys:-

```
SELECT * FROM `cc_tbl_car_review` WHERE expert_title like '%bm%'
SELECT * FROM `cc_tbl_car_review` WHERE expert_title like 'bm%'
SELECT * FROM `cc_tbl_car_review` WHERE expert_title like '%b'
```

This all are not usefull for searching this.if you have any solution then please share it with me.

Comment: than use where expert_title = 'sumthing'

Comment: `WHERE expert_title = 'b'`?

Comment: yes just use where `col` = 'value' ..

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
SELECT * FROM `cc_tbl_car_review` WHERE expert_title ='bm'
```

And when you mean to find whole word matches in a larger string use @Niet_the_Dark_Absol 's answer.

His query will only find the word `cat` in `My cat is brown` and not in `My category color is brown` or `My bobcat is brown`

Comment: How is this an "exact word search"? OP wants to find rows like `'abc bm def'` but not `'abmd'`

Comment: Depends on how you read the question, literally my answer is an EXACT match of the word. Not a whole word match with word boundaries.

Comment: but column expert_title have multiple words.so how it will search?

Comment: I'm sort of basing my answer on the `LIKE` queries given ;)

Comment: Then you mean to find whole words with regexp, look at Niet the Dark Absol answer

Answer (score 1):

Try REGEXP:

```
... WHERE expert_title REGEXP '\bbm\b'
```

The `\b` indicates a word boundary, and in theory that should allow you to match exact words (though in practice it may fail in certain edge cases)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `=` sign instead of `LIKE`. This will look up for exact match in your database.

```
SELECT * FROM `cc_tbl_car_review` WHERE expert_title = 'bm';
```

Comment: but column expert_title have multiple words .so how it will works?

Comment: Then you mean to find whole words with regexp, look at Niet the Dark Absol answer